# Not able to prevent certain users from dropping the table

Tags: sql, azure, ddl, azure-synapse

I am not able to find any way to stop users of some role from dropping the table.

The code I am using is below

```
CREATE ROLE external_users;  
grant Select,Update,Delete,Alter,Execute,Insert,Create View,create Table on database::db_1 to external_users;
deny ALTER ANY USER,ALTER ANY ROLE,CREATE ROLE on database::db_1 to external_users;

--Creating a user in db_1 for the user and then adding it to the above role

CREATE USER user for login user;  
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'external_users', 'user';
```

I denied the DELETE permission but then also the user can drop the tables.(Cannot deny ALTER permission as I want the user to create the table)

I also created a trigger but don't know how to make it enable on specific users or roles.

Basically, I want to prevent users of some roles to drop the tables(users of other roles can perform these functions). They can create the table but cannot drop the table.

Comment: Given the amount that you are allowing them to do, they could utterly destroy any data *contained* in the table. What value do you see, then, in specifically preventing drop? I.e. even without drop they can leave you with a single column table with a nonsense name and no rows.

Comment: They can update, create, and insert but cannot delete or drop any rows or columns. @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Answer (score 0):

If you can `ALTER` a table you can `DROP` the table. It's built into the permission.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: That's why I was asking the questions. Is there any turn around to stop any users to drop the table?